# Datastructure to store an nested element in JSON

Tags: java, json, data-modeling

I am modelling classes in Java to store a JSON , for a particular JSON

```
  "id":1,
  "firstName":"sample",
  "lastName":"person",
   "Books":{
    "bookName":"gone with the wind"
    "isbn":  12345
    }
```

I created a `class person` with `int id , String firstName` etc...
what would be the best way to  store bookName , make a `class Books` with a `String bookName` and `int isbn` , how would I represent books in the person class , As an array? since books always has only one value is there a better way to represent it

Comment: Books have two values, bookName and isbn. And yes, an array.

Answer (score 1):

For json serialization/deserialization, I suggest the jackson library.Here is my code,it works fine on my computer!

I store the json in the file named json.data as following:

---

```
{"id":1,
 "firstName":"sample",
 "lastName":"person",
 "books":[{"bookName":"gone with the wind","isbn":12345}]
}
```

---

### And the code,I omitted the getter/setter to be short

```
public class Book
{
    private String bookName;
    private int isbn;

}

public class BookWriter
{
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Book[] books;
}

public class JSONTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            BookWriter writer=(BookWriter)mapper.readValue(new File("json.data"), BookWriter.class);
            for(Book book:writer.getBooks())
            {
            System.out.println(book.getBookName()+","+book.getIsbn());
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Note: if fields were `public`, you wouldn't even need getters/setters.